# Custom event log Query

Tags: c#, event-log

I have create this custom views event  log call **"Logs"**, and try to access this from C sharp, but on all possible ways i have not been able to get data from it. The custom is filtering to show only display some events and get this events only.

How can i Query data from Custom event log help needed

```
String log = "Logs";
                    EventLog aLog = new EventLog(log, machine);
                    EventLogEntry entry;
                    EventLogEntryCollection entries = aLog.Entries;
                    Stack<EventLogEntry> stack = new Stack<EventLogEntry>();
                    for (int i=index; i < entries.Count;i++)
                    {
                        entry = entries[i];
                        stack.Push(entry);
                        entry = stack.Pop();
                        index = i;
                        long eventid=entry.InstanceId;
                        if (eventid != 4634 && eventid != 4624)
                        {
                            userAccountManager(entry, stack, eventid);

                            ///
                        }
                    }
```

Here's the location of the log:

[image]

Comment: This is the image: http://s3.postimg.org/cw059gz5v/Capture.png, I edit original post and show code

Comment: If I use security instead of Logs works, but on any Custom view i create  is not working

Comment: No ways to read  custom view logs???